# Bedroom/Bathroom Rewiring Design

Tags: electrical

In Oregon:

I am remodeling our master bedroom/bathroom, and moving the location of the bathroom, hence I need to rewire everything.

The house was built in 1989 in the following manner:

1. 20 amp circuit supplying bathroom GFis for two bathrooms (including master)
2. 15 amp circuit providing bedroom receptacles and lighting, and bathroom lighting and fan (no heater).

I want to keep this same design, but I am uncertain if the fan will need a separate circuit from the bedroom receptacles?

Also, I want to add an outdoor receptacle and outdoor light to the bedroom receptacle circuit with the GFI outlet in the receptacle.  Is this allowed to tee into this circuit?

Comment: Thinking about the design functionally, wouldn't you want the bathrooms wired so that a hair dryer could be used in each one simultaneously? A modern hand held hair dryer can be consume 1600 W, so drawing over 13 A at 120 V. I think the receptacles for the two bathrooms need to be on separate 20-A circuits. Our tract house has the two bathrooms wired on one 15-A circuit, but we don't trip breakers because my wife is the only one using a hair dryer. A neighboring  couple with both full baths wired on the same circuit get breaker trips when the wife's female relatives visit.

Answer (score 2):

With bathrooms, Code now gives you two forks in the road.

- One 20A circuit can power **only bathroom receptacles** in any number of bathrooms, but absolutely nothing other than bathroom *receptacles*. Hardwired loads in the bathrooms (lighting, fan) *must* be powered by other household circuits.
- One 20A circuit must power **one bathroom only**, but can power receptacles *and* hardwired loads in **that same bathroom only**. This circuit cannot power anything in any other room.  However, hardwired loads in that bathroom *could* be powered by other household circuits.

Rewire time is a great time to address problems like, as Jim Stewart says, breakers tripping when Mom and daughter try to run hair dryers at once.   Honestly, I wouldn't even consider it excessive to supply *two* 20A receptacle circuits, so the occupant of that bathroom can run a curler and hair dryer at once.  This could even be done with a single 12/3 cable using our old friend the MWBC.

As far as extending the bedroom circuit outside, that is fine.  However I learned not to leave expensive electronic things outdoors. That includes GFCIs.  I would fit a cheaper indoor-rated GFCI+receptacle inside the bedroom at whichever location you tap for the outside extension.  Hang the cable to the outdoor receptacle off the `LOAD` terminals of that GFCI.  Then, fit a plain receptacle outdoors.  It won't deteriorate nearly as fast, and when it does, it's $2.

Answer (score 1):

Code has changed since the home was built. NEC 210.11.c.3 requires the 20 amp bathroom circuit. You can power what you have listed in the bathroom from that 1 circuit see the exception but no other outlets .( the fan can be on this circuit) make sure to have a delay timer for the fan they have been hitting folks on the delay off timer in bathrooms for a while in Lynn, Benton & lane counties for a while now.